# Appx package does not show in Start screen

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, powershell, windows-store, windows-store-app

Recently, I decided I want to grab some applications that were originally shipping with Windows 8 and sideload them to Windows 8.1.

So I just installed Windows 8 in a virtual machine and then grabbed the URL of the appx file of the "Mail, Calendar, People and Messaging" app from Windows Store.

Then, I downloaded the respective appx and went back with it on my Windows 8.1 host.
I fired up Windows PowerShell and tried to sideload the appx using `Add-AppxPackage`. It failed, until I downloaded Visual Studio 2012 and managed to pull from its files the dependencies the app requested (Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.appx and Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.11.00.appx - those are located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs on my PC).

I then installed the 2 dependencies using the `Add-AppxPackage` command and it worked.
Finally, I also managed to install the Mail, Calendar, People and Messaging appx using the same command.

Now, when I type `Get-AppxPackage` in PowerShell, it shows me that I have installed those 3 packages...

Unfortunately, there are no tiles to be found in the Start screen, so I cannot really access the application. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it popped up on the Start screen recently: all I had to do was to resume a pending installation I had (since I installed Windows, I never took the time to click on it) and the 4 tiles for the apps popped up on the Start screen. So I assume one has to have a pending installation for this process to work, but hey, I have now finally found a way to get back the Windows apps I miss from Windows 8.1 !

I have to mention that installing some other app from Windows Store did not work... I tried that, but without luck. It worked only with this pending installation...

Comment: Only 3 of them: Mail, Calendar and People. Messaging has been left out of the party, but I have resurrected it.